# How to disallow committing a subfolder in SVN

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I need to prevent particular subdirectory from receiving commits.
In other directories, developers can still commit.

How can I write a svn pre-commit hook to disallow their commits?
(it won't be same as adding that subdirectory into their ignore list).

Answer (score 1):

Configuring a pre-commit hook script is not the only option.

You can [configure path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) to be able to set 'No Access', 'Read Only', 'Read / Write' access rules on repository items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `svnlook dirs-changed $1 -t $2` ($1 and $2 are repo_path and transaction used in the pre-commit)) to get a list of directories changed, and if the results contain the particular directory (pass it through grep or a similar regex-checking tool) then write an error message to stderr and return 1.